# How to fix 'defineConfig is not a function' error?

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuetify.js

I have `npm` 8.1.2 version installed. I created Vue2 project. All worked fine until I have installed Vuetify2 (`npm add vuetify`). Now, when I start the app using `npm run serve` the following error comes up:

> ERROR  Error loading D:\XYZ\project\vue.config.js:
> ERROR  TypeError: defineConfig is not a function TypeError:
> defineConfig is not a function

I upgraded all existing packages to the newest versions:

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve --open",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.26.0",
    "npm-check-updates": "^16.3.15",
    "vue": "^3.2.41",
    "vue-router": "^4.1.5",
    "vuetify": "^2.6.12",
    "vuex": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.8",
    "sass": "~1.55.0",
    "sass-loader": "^13.1.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.5.8",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.13",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.9.2"
  }
}
```

and my `vue.config.js` looks like this:

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: [
    'vuetify'
  ]
})
```

I don't know where the problem is. I also have another Vue2+Vuetify2 project (which I created a few months ago) which works fine when I run it with npm run serve. But the new one is not working.

Comment: It's `npm i` (for install) usually, it's `yarn add`. But I don't think that it's the main issue here. Otherwise, the `defineConfig` doesn't look like it's tied to Vuetify here.

Comment: At the same time, [that one](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues?q=is%3Aissue+defineConfig+is+not+a+function) does not give a lot of results neither.

Comment: `defineConfig` is just a convenience - it adds type definitions so that your IDE will be able to provide better code suggestions (Intelli-Sense). It is not actually needed - you can export a plain JavaScript object from `vue.config.js` while not importing `defineConfig`